# Linux Mint Volume Buttons Past 100%

Tags: linux-mint, audio, cinnamon

On the latest Linux Mint, in the sound settings we are able to increase the volume past 100%, to 150%. Sometimes this can be useful when coming across very quiet videos.

My keyboard hotkeys are configured to increase and decrease volume, but the increase only goes as far as 100%. Is there any way I can make it go to 150%?

Answer (score 5):

To get the volume 150% run the following command:

```
pactl -- set-sink-volume 0 150%
```

Or using the GUI , install the `pavucontrol`  package then run it from the terminal :`pavucontrol` , then modify the `%volume`

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer, but I'm not looking to use the terminal to change the volume setting.

Comment: Great, this works.

Answer (score 1):

In Cinnamon you can install **Sound with apps volume** applet. 
Then go to its settings and enable **Volume: 150%**.

Use the applet for controlling volume instead of default **Sound** applet.

This doesn't allow to control system volume with keyboard, but at least you don't have to go to the settings nor use terminal.